# Always show all members in member list in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

There are few related answers already on SO but older than 10 years, secondly I'm sure I have disabled/enabled some option somewhere because since then I have this issue.

Following is member list when typing (dot):

[image]

Following is a member list I had prior to messing with options (which I want back):

[image]

As you can see the issue is that member list is now a lot shorter and to increase it manually you have to click on "+" button in bottom left corner, this wasn't needed before.

I can't recall which option did this but I'm sure it's somewhere in:

> Text editor -> C\C++

Comment: You can check if `Enable Predictive IntelliSense` is false in Text editor -> C\C++ -> Experimental

Comment: I did and we'll see if this works, because list size seems to be random, sometimes short sometimes not, thanks for suggestion!

Comment: @Dylan Yes this was indeed due to predictive intellisense! thank you! Sorry for long response, I didn't use VS for some time.